# Laravel eloquent sum column is not appearing in results

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

I have the next database:

[image]

Therefore I have three php models `Purchase`, `Supplier` and `PurchaseDetail`.
My model `Supplier` has a relation `hasMany` with `Purchase`:

```
public function purchases() {
        return $this->hasMany(Purchase::class, 'supplier_id');
    }
```

And the model `Purchase` has a relation `hasMany` with `PurchaseDetail` :

```
public function details(){
        return $this->hasMany(PurchaseDetail::class, 'purchase_id');
    }
```

From here there is not problems with the relations. The problem comes for me when I trying of get the qty total for all purchases of each supplier. I did the next query:

```
$collectionCenters = Supplier::whereHas('purchases', function($q1){
                    $q1->whereHas('details', function($q2){
                        $q2->select(\DB::raw('SUM(qty) as purchasesQtyKg'))
                        ->where('unit', 'kg');
                    });
            })->where('supplier_type','=','juridic_person')
            ->get();
```

Output query from laravel debug bar:

```
select * from `suppliers` where exists (select * from `purchases` where `suppliers`.`id` = `purchases`.`supplier_id` and exists (select SUM(qty) as purchasQtyKg from `purchase_details` where `purchases`.`id` = `purchase_details`.`purchase_id` and `unit` = 'kg') and `purchases`.`deleted_at` is null) and `supplier_type` = 'juridic_person'
```

As you can see, I'm using the relations with whereHas directive. However nothing happens, it oly throws the three suppliers of my database but the column with alias `purchasesQtyKg` it not appears in the results:

[image]

Phpmyadmin output from query:

[image]

I also did something like this:

```
 $collectionCenters = Supplier::where('supplier_type','=','juridic_person')
                            ->with(['purchases.details' => function($query){
                                $query->select(\DB::raw("SUM(purchase_details.qty) as purchaseQtyKg"))
                                ->where('unit', $this->unit);
                            }])->get();
```

But nothing happens, I'm afraid because this should work. I will appreciate any idea guys for fix this problem. Thanks you so much.

Comment: Hi, you may use the `withSum` method on the queryBuilder.

Comment: Hi dear, please give me one example. I should uses it inside the whereHas?

Comment: what is happening in the `whereHas` doesn't change the result set (it is just restricting the result), so that won't be adding anything to the query for you to select

Comment: Probably it's happening

Answer (score 1):

`whereHas` doesn't change the result set (it is just restricting the result).
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence

**You may use something like this in laravel 8**

**withSum**: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#other-aggregate-functions

```
$collectionCenters = Supplier::query()
    ->whereHas('purchases', function ($q1) {
        $q1->whereHas('details', function ($q2) {
            $q2->where('unit', 'kg');
        });
    })
    ->with([
        'purchases' => function ($query) {
            return $query->withSum('details', 'qty')->where('unit', 'kg');
        }
    ])
    ->where('supplier_type', '=', 'juridic_person')
    ->get();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But it throwed this error: 1054 Unknown column 'unit' in 'where clause' (SQL: select `purchases`.*, (select sum(`purchase_details`.`qty`) from `purchase_details` where `purchases`.`id` = `purchase_details`.`purchase_id`) as `details_sum_qty` from `purchases` where `purchases`.`supplier_id` in (4, 5, 7) and `unit` = kg and `purchases`.`deleted_at` is null)` It seems that the problem is inside of the whereHas('details'). Now I'm considering adding a hasManyThrough inside model Supplier to join the supplier with detail_purchase through purchase.

Comment: Hi @esam eisa Sorry, I removed the with(['purchases']..) and the code works but is not adding.. The problem seems to be here   return $query->withSum('details', 'qty')->where('unit', 'kg');

Comment: Fixed! using a hasManyThrough relation:        $collectionCenters = Supplier::withCount(['detail_purchases as purchaseQtys' => function($query){
                                 return $query->select(\DB::raw('SUM(qty)'))->where('unit', '=', $this->unit);
                             }])->where('supplier_type','=','persona_juridica')
                             ->orderBy('purchaseQtys','desc')
                             ->get();

Comment: Great, thanks for sharing the final answer, have a good day

Comment: I pleasure also help. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed my issue creating a `hasManyThrough` relation inside my `Supplier` model:

```
public function detail_purchases(){
        return $this->hasManyThrough(PurchaseDetail::class, Purchase::class);
    }
```

Then using Eloquent I can use this relation:

```
   $collectionCenters = Supplier::withCount(['detail_purchases as purchaseQtys' => function($query){
                             return $query->select(\DB::raw('SUM(qty)'))->where('unit', '=', $this->unit);
                         }])->where('supplier_type','=','persona_juridica')
                         ->orderBy('purchaseQtys','desc')
                         ->get();
```

Output:

```
#attributes: array:9 [▼
        "id" => 4
        "supplier_type" => "persona_juridica"
        "department_id" => 14
        "province_id" => 1403
        "district_id" => 140308
        "community_id" => null
        "created_at" => "2021-11-04 09:55:49"
        "updated_at" => "2021-11-04 09:55:49"
        "purchaseQtys" => "6"
```

I also created magic methods or attributes:

```
   public function getQtySoldKgAttribute(){
        return  $this->detail_purchases()->where('unit','kg')->sum('qty');
   
   }
   public function getQtySoldTonsAttribute(){
        return $this->detail_purchases()->where('unit','t')->sum('qty');
  }

  public function getQtySoldGramsAttribute(){
    return $this->detail_purchases()->where('unit','g')->sum('qty');
 }
 public function getQtySoldGallonsAttribute(){
    return $this->detail_purchases()->where('unit','gal')->sum('qty');
 }
 public function getQtySoldLitersAttribute(){
    return $this->detail_purchases()->where('unit','l')->sum('qty');
 }
 public function getQtySoldMillilitersAttribute(){
    return $this->detail_purchases()->where('unit','ml')->sum('qty');
 }
```

When you use a sum firt we need to add where condition and then the `sum` directive, if you add first the `sum` and then the `where` it will not works.

Cheers!.